# How to convert columns to index in dataframe with python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df like this:

```
             A              B        
days         1     2   3    1   2   3     
msno                                                                          
111          0  77.0   0  0.0   0   0   
222          0   0.0   0  0.0   0   0   
333          0   0.0   0  0.0   0   0   
444          0   0.0   0  0.0   0   0
```

Could someone tell me how to convert columns A and B to index?
like this:

```
days              1     2   3      
msno    features                                
111      A        0  77.0   0  
         B        0.0   0   0 

222      A        0   0.0   0  
         B        0.0   0   0 

333      A        0   0.0   0
         B        0.0   0   0

444      A        0   0.0   0
         B        0.0   0   0
```

Comment: Try stacking your data: `df.stack()`

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [`.stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
df = YOUR_DATAFRAME
df.stack(0)
# 0 is mean your 'A','B'
# 1 is mean your 1,2,3
```

or unstack can convert rows to columns